# merging one column from multiple rows based on another column

Tags: awk

Trying to merge multiple rows into 1 based on first column.

Ex. File1

```
S784    CHST5,TMEM231  
S784    TM4SF20  
S784    TMEM184A  
U531    5S_rRNA,C3orf33  
U604    LRRC69  
U586    PLEKHA5,C8orf77  
U586    ZNF252,LINGO2
```

output file

```
S784    CHST5,TMEM231,TM4SF20,TMEM184A  
U531    5S_rRNA,C3orf33  
U604    LRRC69  
U586    PLEKHA5,C8orf77,ZNF252,LINGO2
```

This is what I have so far, which works but giving me an extra comma I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of...

```
awk -F'\t' '{a[$1]++; list[$1]=list[$1]","$2} END {for (i in a) print i,FS,list[i]}' File1 > output
```

current output

```
S784    ,CHST5,TMEM231,TM4SF20,TMEM184A  
U531    ,5S_rRNA,C3orf33  
U604    ,LRRC69  
U586    ,PLEKHA5,C8orf77,ZNF252,LINGO2
```

I've also tried using `list[$1]=$2","list[$1]` but that still gives me an extra comma just at the end instead of the beginning of column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1]",":"")$2 }END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' OFS='\t' file
```

- `a[$1]` - array `a` is indexed with the 1st field value `$1`
- `($1 in a? a[$1]",":"")$2` - while iterating through the records check if the current key `$1` is already in array `a` (performed by *ternary* condition `$1 in a?`), if so - concatenate the previous value `a[$1]` with current value `$2` using `,` as separator; otherwise - just assign with the current value `$2`

---

The output:

```
U604    LRRC69
U586    PLEKHA5,C8orf77,ZNF252,LINGO2
U531    5S_rRNA,C3orf33
S784    CHST5,TMEM231,TM4SF20,TMEM184A
```

Comment: Your are awesome.  Thank you.  Would you mind explaining what your code is doing so I can understand more and hopefully have to ask fewer question :)